# OpenGL Screensaver won't work on Nvidia newest driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, opengl, screensaver

I just upgraded from 14.04LTS to 16.04LTS 64bit...my opengl screensaver won't run on the newest version of the Nvidia graphics driver 304.132....I have to force run the lowest one 304.131, but am still having issues.  This is a Nvidia NVS 120M or GeForce Go Series 7400.  When screensaver kicks in, the screen goes black with amber writing in the upper left corner of the screen...

Comment: Apparently, it's [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1639180).

Comment: My other issue is, that if I was to downgrade to the 304.131 driver, then none of my fb games will function, because of Adobe Flash...